# Defining an array out of method in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am new in C, I have a question and I searched  in here and google but I didn't get answer.

```
int main(){
char name[];
name = "PeerNet";   
}
```

this is wrong I know but

```
char name[];
int main(){
scanf("%s", name); // I write PeerNet in scanf.
}
```

this is allowed.

What is the difference? And how compiler act?

Comment: Neither variant compiles with gcc. Are you missing something?

Comment: How are you compiling this?  Please post your command

Comment: FWIW, Clang compiles the second one (minus the assignment) with a warning that it is assumed to have one element.

Comment: @Don Shankin I am sorry I paste wrong code. Now is right.

Comment: So... your question is about the difference between `char name[];` at file scope and at block scope? The first snippet fails to compile before the invalid assignment is reached...

Comment: Yes I know the first one is wrong and give me error. But the second one fine. What is the difference? Because I declare first and assign later

Comment: see [6.9.2 External object definitions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a difference in how initialization works vs. what `scanf` does. When you want to initialize a character array to a string, you have to do it right when you declare the array. The initialization then copies characters from the string literal into the array. Assigning a string literal to a character array is not allowed at any other time, because this copying and filling of the array process only happens at initialization. At any other time, such as saying:

```
name = "PeerNet";
```

The compiler sees this as telling the pointer to the character array to point somewhere else, which shouldn't happen -- that array pointer has to remain bound to its own array.

However, `scanf` follows this copy and fill process even after the array is declared. So with a statement like:

```
scanf("%s", name);
```

`scanf` will copy the characters in the inputted string into the array called `name`.

Comment: Out of interest, what's the size of the array in the second variant when `scanf` copies values into it?

Answer (score 0):

please use index number for array if you are not initializing. You can write like:

```
int main(){
char name[8];
strcpy(name,"PeerNet");   
}
```

or

```
int main(){
char *name;
name="PeerNet";   
}
```

The error you are doing is, you are trying to assign a char * type to char type, (name is a char type and "PeerNet" is a char * type), which you cannot do.

And you cannot assign a whole string to char type because char type is one byte and string is starting from first character more than one byte. So, use strcpy to assign that string to your char type array.

And one more neither of your codes will run! Even if you make your character array global, you should give index number (plus one for null) as below:

```
char name[8];
int main(){
    name="PeerNet";   
    }
```

Of course this

```
char name[];
int main(){
scanf("%s", name); // I write PeerNet in scanf.
}
```

will work but in undefined way, actually it's not encouraged, you might be getting correct results now, but in future if you extend code we cannot guaranty.

You are writing to unallocated memory (beyond the array). In order to compile this, the compiler is allocating at least one element, and you're then writing beyond that.

Comment: I didn't mention char, I wrote char array. I can assing whole string to char array as you can see. And why should I give a number? It can size itself automatically as I know.

Comment: I used char because each letter in your string is a char right? And no you cannot assign it like you did, you can do it like this:                                                             char name[]="PeerNet";                                                    Sorry it cannot size itself if you do like what you did, it can only size itself if you declare and initialize in the same line of your code!

Comment: Hah, are you kidding? If you are talking about my first code, I emphasized "It is wrong I know".  If you are talking about second code, it works! And I can print the length of array So it can size itself!

Comment: That is what I was saying girl! Its happening here but it's a bad practice! It might give you correct output now but if your code increases we cannot guaranty that! It will be an undefined behaviour! So better follow correct way! In your case you are clearly disobeying C rules and you should never do that! As you a beginner you start following what is exact from now only! It will be good for you in future, if you satisfy yourselves with codes  !like this you will face trouble in future

Comment: Now I got what you say. But above comments, you said you cannot, I said I can. Now you say you shouldn't, yes you are right. Already I just do that but it's just an example and it confuse me. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Try this example, you will come to know what I am trying to say, okay!                                                                                                                             #include <stdio.h>
char name[];
int a;
int main(){
scanf("%s", name);
scanf("%d", &a);
printf("%s",name);
printf("%d",a);

return 0;
} Take care!

Comment: Does it work fine for you? How come?Hmmm lets see! I am posting my output, please post yours too!                                                                My inputs: jeevan
123                                                                   My output: jeev{123 see undefined behaviour

Comment: I suppose I don't understand each other. What do you want to show me?
and my output: PeerNet2014

Comment: See my inputs and outputs are different undefined outputs I got!

Comment: Did I wrote wrong code or you? I wrote what you post here. And my screenshot;
http://i62.tinypic.com/2w20aic.png